# how to create soap Api for customer login in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm new in magento,

I want to create soap api for customer login.

**i create role and user through web services->soap/xml-RPC role and soap/xml-RPC users.** but i don't know the next step,

please help.Thanks.